# xCode: TableView cant see/acces all cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

When I press a button called "AllOK" I want the object.selectedIndex to be 0. This works perfectly with the cells that is visible. But it won't acces the cells which isn't viewable on the app / screen. If you scroll down and get vision of them, it will check them, but i want it to do it, without having to scroll down.

Do anyone know how to get the tableview to know that it "also" got the cells that it cannot see?

My code for my tableview and for the button:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FancyCell"];
    cell = nil;
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"FancyCell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        // add the segmentedControl when you create a new cell
        UIImage *correctImageGreen = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage *correctImageGul = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gul.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage *correctImageRed = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage *correctImageGray = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: correctImageGreen, correctImageGul, correctImageRed, correctImageGray, nil];
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(310, 7, 150, 30);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl];

        // add an action so we can change our model if the view changes
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        // use a tag so we can retrieve the segmentedControl later
        segmentedControl.tag = 42;
    }
    // either if the cell could be dequeued or you created a new cell,
    // segmentedControl will contain a valid instance
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:42];

    UIImage *comment = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-hvid"];
    UIImage *imageRef = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-hvid"];
    UIImageView *commentView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: comment];
    UIImageView *imageRefView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imageRef];
    commentView.frame = CGRectMake(625, 5, 30, 30);
    imageRefView.frame = CGRectMake(515, 5, 30, 30);
    commentView.tag = 98;
    imageRefView.tag = 99;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    boolean_t didGetStates = [defaults boolForKey:@"didGetStates"];

    MBFancyObject *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    if (didGetStates) {

        // State
        NSDictionary *dic = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (object.beingEdited == -1) {
            int selectedState = [[dic valueForKey:@"State"] intValue];
            object.selectedIndex = selectedState;
        }

        // Comment & ImageRef
        int comment = [[dic valueForKey:@"Comment"] intValue];
        int imageRef = [[dic valueForKey:@"Foto"] intValue];
        if (comment == 0) {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:commentView];
        }
        else {
            [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:98]removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if (imageRef == 0) {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageRefView];
        }
        else {
            [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99]removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = object.title;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = object.selectedIndex;
    object.currentIndexRow = indexPath.row;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)allOK:(id)sender {
    for (MBFancyObject *object in _objects) {
        object.selectedIndex = 0;
        object.beingEdited = 0;
    }
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Comment: So cellForRowAtIndexPath will only be called when the cell becomes visible on screen. You may need some other kind of initialization for this to work properly

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input! I am fairly new to developing app and I wondered if you could tell me which initialization I should use instead? :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I hadn't noticed this at my first comment, but your problem here is obvious. You are not properly dequeueing cells from the cell pool, and therefore when you scroll, you are creating a brand new cell EVERY time, which causes them not to have your selected index the way you want. I am pretty sure that your solution lies right here:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FancyCell"];
cell = nil;
if (!cell) {
```

You are dequeuing a cell properly, but then immediately setting it to nil, meaning it will ALWAYS go through the !cell check and will ALWAYS create a new cell. Try removing this line and working with the dequeued cell.

Edit:

Since that didn't do it, this is what else I would try: 
Create a call to the method `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, and in this call check a boolean flag that you set to see if the segmented control at that index should be at index 0 or not. So basically whenever a cell is about to be shown, you check if it's segmented control should be set to index 0, and if it should, set it's index to 0.

Comment: Hi agian. I tried to remove the cell = nil; line but still not working as it should ;-( U got any other suggestions how I could fix this problem? Maybe just a function that scrolls down an then back up when the view loads? :)

Comment: One thing you could do, although I'm not sure how great of a solution it is, is to have an array of segmentedControls that you initialize in the viewDidLoad method. That way, when you press AllOk, you simply go through and set all of those to the right value. Then, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you simply take the segmented control for the index at which are at.

Comment: As I have mentioned I'am fairly new to coding iOS application and therefore i wonder if you would like to maybe help me out. Either give me some of the code or if u would like then use teamviewer? :-) Thanks

Comment: I understand that you are new to this, so let me be more clear. Do you currently have an implementation of viewDidLoad? If you don't, then all you need to do is add it in by calling [super viewDidLoad] (make sure you have this!), and then adding your own code in. Do you understand the concept of an array of UISegmentedControls? One question I have for you is how big is your objects array, and is it fixed, or variable?

Comment: I currently have the viewDidLoad implementaion. I don't get the array of UISegmentedControls :-( The number of objects in the object array is variable, but between 15 and 25. Thanks agian.

Comment: See edited answer, which goes in a different direction. I don't think the array of segmented controls will work with a variable length table.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home from school :-) Is there a chance that u could help me over TeamViewer if it still not working? ;-) The reason is that I don't got alot of time to get the application done. Thanks agian!

Comment: Hi again. I tested it and I might think that we maybe have a misconception. The method willDisplayCell (for me) does not make sence because I need to set cell that are outside the users view and NOT displayed ;-) U want to teamviewer and help me? :-)

Comment: Hi sorry super busy, what I'm saying is when they'r about to be displayed, decide whether or not the segmented control should be at index 0...

Comment: But my problem is not getting the segmentedcontrol index when the view loads. My problem is that I can't set the segmentedcontrols indexes that are outside the tableview. So if i for example scroll 3 cells down it will change these cells segmentedcontrols aswell as all the other cells it have already seen. But the rest of the segmentedcontrols in the cells in the bottom that it have not seen yet, does not get the segmentedcontrol index changed :-(

Comment: You're not understanding what I'm saying I suppose: I am saying that instead of changing all of them all at once, just check when your about to display each one if the index should be reset or not. If it should, do it, otherwise just display it normally.

Comment: Is there anyway I can get you to help me over teamviewer? I would really appreciate if that was possible! :-) Contact me over mail if there is any chance you got a little time to help me. My mail adress is mikkel@vesterled.dk, thanks again!